# ActiveRecord eagerloading with STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have this situation.

1. Model A.
2. Models B and C that inherit from A.
3. C has a property, parent_id that points to a B.
4. B has a parent_id property that is nil.
5. Both B and C have special users.
6. C's special users are the special users it owns and the special users of B.

Now I originally expressed this relationship as

```
# in C
belongs_to :B, class_name: "B", foreign_key: "parent_id", inverse_of: :schools
has_many :own_special_users, -> { User.special_users }, through: :users
has_many :parent_special_users, through: :district, source: :special_users

def special_users
  own_special_users + parent_special_users
end
```

This is what B looks like

```
# in B
 has_many :cs, class_name: "C", foreign_key: "parent_id"
```

This is what A looks like

```
  has_many :special_users, -> { User.special_users }, through: :special_users
```

Now this worked! However, eagerloading wasn't working. The reason I know this because when I did

```
ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new.preload(instances_of_a, [:special_users])
```

through ActiveLogger in the rails console, nothing executed (I think this means that the preloader didn't actually execute the SQL? - I'm new to ActiveRecord). I also know that it didn't work because I have perf tests that count the number of sql queries that are executed, and I have extras everywhere that come from this change (looking at the stack trace).

I do think that because the preloading worked before - that it might be better to express this relationship solely within A.

So I have two questions

1. Why is preloading/eagerloading not working with my expressed relationships?
2. How can I express the above solely in A?

Thanks - also let me know if it's not clear - I know it's complicated and might require more context.